# Can raspistill connect with rtpjpegpay by pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, raspistill

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -w 800 -h 600 -tl 0  -t 0 -o - | test-launch "fdsrc ! image/jpeg ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay"
stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
```

But I failed to use `vlc` in `win10` to connect with raspberry pi3. I dont know where the problem is. I can't get any error information. I success in running this command :

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 1920 -w 1080 -fps 30  -o - | ./test-launch " fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "
```

So, I think my command is okay. Could someone help me?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HaHa, I think I have resolved my own question ( 哈哈哈，我认为我解决了自己的问题 )。Now, let me help you.
The server is

raspistill -w 800 -h 600 -tl 0  -t 0 -o - | test-launch "fdsrc ! image/jpeg,width=800,height=600 ! jpegparse !  rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96"

The client is

gst-launch-1.0.exe rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.30:8554/test ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse !  multifilesink location="%d.jpeg"

or

gst-launch-1.0.exe rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.30:8554/test ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse !  jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

vlc can't  resolv the flow from server temporarily. So don't to use it !